# Why is my splice deleting all but the first instead of only the one specified?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, splice

For a given array, when I run the splice everything but the first entry is deleted. However I would expect only the selected entry to be deleted. I suspect this has something to do with how my i is set up but I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
removethisone = (i) => {this.setState(state=>({list: state.list.splice(i,1)}))}

    <ul>
    {this.state.list.map((entry, i)=><li key={i}><button onClick={this.removethisone}>{i+1}</button>{entry}</li>)}
    </ul>
```

Comment: If you use splice, it's better to go in reverse through the list. Meaning in your case write a function with a for loop that counts from array length to 0. Otherwise, you mess up the following indices.

Comment: Did you look at what splice returns??? Code is working as expected. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `Array.splice` method returns the removed items from the array.

You need to do something like this:

```js
removethisone = (i) => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const nextState = [ ...state.list ]
    nextState.splice(i, 1)

    return { list: nextList }
  })
}
```

For example, run the code below to see the ouput:

```js
// This is what your code does
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let removedNumbers = numbers.splice(2, 1)
numbers = removedNumbers

console.log(numbers);
console.log(removedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working exactly as you described because that is how [splice works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

The splice method returns an array of the items that are removed. You are storing the items you removed back into the state. Hence why you get what you removed.

```
removethisone = (i) => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const list = state.list;
    const removedElems = list.splice(i, 1);
    console.log(removedElems);
    return {
      list
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I was expecting splice to give back the array with the items removed, I didn't realize I had to get the array again.